# change routing name dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have to modify the routes file in order to have SEO improvement.
This is my context, a rails backend generate a JSON feed with the route's name in, I have to read it and change the default name.
For example, I have this:

```
get '/people' => 'people#show', as: :people
```

and I'd like to change /people in some value read from my JSON feed.
I created a class to get the JSON object in my app

```
class JSONDatabase
  def initialize(kind_of_site)
    @kind_of_site = kind_of_site
  end

  def fetch_database_remote(url)
    JSON.parse(open(url).read)
  end
end
```

but how can i access it in routes file?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to modify your application's routes. What you can do is define a wild card route that leads to a unique controller where you read the updated route. This approach is kind of hackish but gives you the unlimited routes you need without modifying the routes.

Your config/routes.rb file would look something like this:

```
resources :defined_models
root to: 'controller#action'

# At last we define the wildcard route
get '/:route' => 'routing_controller#routing_action'
```

Then, at this routing action we can do the job of seeing if this route (now defined in the params[:route] variable) corresponds to the modified one. Just remember to redirect to a 404 if the route given is not defined, since with this approach you loose the Rails default way of dealing with undefined routes.